# Prove this inequality $1\le \sum _{cyc}\frac{a}{1+bc}\le \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. Prove that
$$1\le\dfrac{a}{1+bc}+\dfrac{b}{1+ca}+\dfrac{c}{1+ab}\le\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$$

---

*) $LHS\le \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4} \Rightarrow LHS^2\le \frac{27}{16}$

$\Leftrightarrow \left(1+1+1\right)\left(\sum _{cyc}\frac{a^2}{\left(ab+1\right)^2}\right)\le \frac{27}{16}\Leftrightarrow \sum _{cyc}\frac{a^2}{\left(1+ab\right)^2}\le \frac{9}{16}$

We have: 
$\frac{a^2}{\left(ab+1\right)^2}=\frac{a^2}{\left(ab+a^2+b^2+c^2\right)^2}\le \frac{a^2}{\left(ab+bc+ab+ac\right)^2}\le \frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{a}{ab+bc}+\frac{a}{ac+ab}\right)^2$

$\Rightarrow \sum _{cyc}\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{a}{ab+bc}+\frac{a}{ac+ab}\right)^2\le \frac{9}{16}$

$$\Leftrightarrow \left(\frac{b}{bc+ab}+\frac{b}{bc+ac}\right)^2+\left(\frac{c}{ac+ab}+\frac{c}{ac+bc}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a}{ab+bc}+\frac{a}{ac+ab}\right)^2\le 9=\sqrt{3}^2+\sqrt{3}^2+\sqrt{3}^2$$

It looks easier than before but i can't continue. Help me
*)$LHS\ge 1$I haven't got idea about this problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the left inequality.

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{1+bc}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{a+abc}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+abc)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a+b+c+\frac{(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)}{3}}=\frac{3(a+b+c)}{3+ab+ac+bc}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$3(a+b+c)\geq3+ab+ac+bc$$ or
$$9(a+b+c)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq(3(a^2+b^2+c^2)+ab+ac+bc)^2.$$
Let $a^2+b^2+c^2=k(ab+ac+bc).$

Thus, $k\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$9(k+2)k\geq(3k+1)^2$$ or
$$12k-1\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Your right inequality is wrong.

Try $c\rightarrow0^+$ and $a=b\rightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$

Comment: The equality occur when ?

Comment: @Word Shallow The equality does not occur, but $b=c\rightarrow0^+$ gives an infimum.